# Changing background image to color on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, background-image, background-color

I'm trying to change the background of a div from an image to color when mouse hovers over it. I have managed to almost accomplish it but the color also goes over the text inside the div.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h3>LIPSUM DOLORES DILORES DUM DUM</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
    since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
    essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/127028/pexels-photo-127028.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

div h3,
div p,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div h3,
div p {
  color: red;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j65k4LtL/

Comment: take a look at some example https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/advanced-css-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```css
.outer {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/127028/pexels-photo-127028.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.outer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.outer:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
 
}
.inner{
  position: relative;
}

div h3,
div p,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div h3,
div p {
  color: red;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>
  LIPSUM DOLORES DILORES DUM DUM
  </h3>
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

create inner container and position it as relative.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!